# Spring property value - res: URI

Tags: spring, properties

I've been using spring for years but can't seem to find documentation on this one.  If I have a spring bean configured like this:

```
<bean id="myBeanInstance" class="org.mybean">
    <property name="path" value="res:a-string-goes-here"/>
</bean>
```

Is the value being interpreted as purely a string?  How does 'res:' affect anything and where is it being interpreted?  Any pointers to the appropriate docs would be fantastic.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the value is interpreted purely as string... 
Unless you have a **BeanFactoryPostProcessor**, such as weirdly configured *PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer* or some custom *BeanFactoryPostProcessor* to take care of such values.

Note also, that since Spring 3 the ':' is the default separator for default property values, i.e. if you have *PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer* with default setting, the value "${res:whatever}" would be treated as a property 'res' with default value 'whatever'.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense but Where is the specific documentation for this?

Comment: On BeanFactoryPostProcessors: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-factory-postprocessors . On PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer . On default values - not found in a reference, but explained here, for example: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/spring-property-placeholder-configurer-a-few-not-so-obvious-options.html